# how to interlock list-style with background-image?

Tags: html, css

the title is kind of misleading, but I had no idea how to describe my problem in one sentence.

I’m working on a webdesign for an old company that has a subtle timebar as a part of their corporate identity.

Employees have their own profile-pages and I would like to make their job histories look like timebars.

Maybe you have an idea how this could be managed.

Every line needs to have a lightgrey stroke, except for the first row that needs a longer and darker stroke. I also want it to be responsive. For the case I’m changing the line-height, the solution still needs to work.

Thank you for your ideas!

Example image:
http://www.yoops.de/di-JEYS.jpg

Comment: [This is off topic (reason #1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below and adjust the properties as needed.

```css
ul li:first-of-type { /* Refers to the 1st Li of the UL's */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
li {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '-';
  left: -10px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul li:first-of-type:after {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  top: -4px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li>John Johnson</li>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Mike Michael</li>
  <li>Chelsea</li>
  <li>Barcelona</li>
  <li>Real Madrid</li>
</ul>
```